# How to do EnumDropdownListFor inside a for loop

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, enums

I have the following for loop where the Type is an enum. I want to loop through the form and for each route allow a dropdown of the types.

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Routes.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Routes[" + index + "].Id", Model.Routes[i].Id)
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor("Routes[" + index + "].Id", Model.Routes[i].Type)
        @Html.Hidden("Routes[" + index + "].Name", Model.Routes[i].Name)
        @Html.CheckBox("Routes[" + index + "].IsChecked", Model.Routes[i].IsChecked)
        @Model.Routes[i].Name<br />
        index++;
    }

public class RouteModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public RouteType Type { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public enum RouteType
{
    Transit,
    Air,
    Bus
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make the MVC5 EnumDropDownListFor helper to work inside the for loop. Doesn't look like I may be able to, though I thought I'd ask in case someone had the same issue and discovered an alternative or got theirs to work.

EnumDropDownListFor (MSDN) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn550750(v=vs.118).aspx - This is helper I am using, it is not my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being that I didn't have the correct syntax, forgot the model => part. #n00b

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => Model.Routes[i].Type, "None")
```

Comment: And you should be using the strongly typed helpers for the other properties too `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Routes[i].ID)` and `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Routes[i].IsChecked)` :)

Comment: Agree, thank you. I noticed that it wasn't the best approach while I was trying to figure things out.